# Prove that there is not a retraction of the Möbius band to its boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, mobius-band

I would like a hint to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ be the Möbius band and $A$ its boundary (which is a circumference). Prove that there is not a retraction $r:X \rightarrow A$.

Each try I did gave no solution.

Any hint to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental group of a Moebius band is just $\mathbb{Z}$ (you can see that as it is homotopy equivalent to a circle). Pick a loop that generates it. If you don't know much about the fundamental group, just pick a circle that runs through the middle of the Moebius band; notice, it should go around once, not twice like the boundary.

Now, if there was a retraction this loop should map to a loop in the boundary. Is that possible? Why not? Can the class of the loop change in a retraction?

---

Edit: Extra hint:

What happens if you pre-compose with the inclusion $A \rightarrow X$ ? There are two maps induced $$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ What do we know about the first, and what do we know about their composition?

Comment: I don't understand something, the intuitive idea is clear, but I don't know how to formalize this idea. If $r:X\rightarrow A$ is the retraction, what is the problem with the induces mapping $r_*:\pi(X)=\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \pi(A)=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What happens if you compose with the inclusion $A \rightarrow X$ afterwards?

Comment: Functoriality is the keyword here.

Comment: Precompose means $ir$ or $ri$? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: $r\circ i: A\rightarrow X\rightarrow A$

Comment: I know that $r_*$ must be surjective and $r_*i_*$ has to be the identity map of $\mathbb{Z}$. Why is this a contradiction. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Because the map that is induced by $i$ is multiplication by 2 (can you see that?..) So now, your map $r:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ should satisfy $r(2n)=n$. But what do we know about any map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I am sure that $i_*(n)=2n$, I get it intuitively, how can be done this formally? I think that since $r_*$ has to be surjective then $r_*(1)=\pm 1$ (indeed it has to be an isomorphism) and then $r_*(2n)=2r_*(n)=\pm 2 n = n$ which implies $\pm 2=1$ a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: To do it formally you need to describe a loop that generates the fundamental group of the Moebius band, and see how many times you need to take that loop to get something homotopic to the boundary. To find such a loop the best way is to follow the proof that your $\pi_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. That is via the deformation retraction to the circle _inside_ the Moebius strip. Now, you just need to show that the boundary of the Moebius strip is homotopic to twice the "median" circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22682/discussion-between-theo-and-yotas-trejos).